# Function composition in C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++14

My aim was to create a function which behaves like the operator `.` in Haskell.

Here is what I made:

```
template <typename F>
auto compose(F&& f)
{
    return [a = std::move(f)](auto&&... args){
        return a(std::move(args)...);
    };
}

template <typename F1, typename F2, typename... Fs>
auto compose(F1&& f1, F2&& f2, Fs&&... fs)
{
    return compose(
        [first = std::move(f1), second = std::move(f2)]
        (auto&&... args){
            return second(first(std::move(args)...));
        },
        std::move(fs)...
    );
}
```

Possible usage:

```
int main()
{
const auto f = compose([](const auto a, const auto b){return a + b;},
                       [](const auto n){return n * n;},
                       [](const auto n){return n + 2;});
std::cout << f(3, 2) << std::endl;
// should output 27 ( (3 + 2) * (3 + 2) + 2 )
}
```

The full source with a few more examples may be found [here](https://github.com/nestoroprysk/FunctionComposition/tree/b729244ecedf9c6ef3fad85b8a2398d1b084456d).

I'm not sure whether to use `std::move` or `std::forward`. Which one is better? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably do want `std::forward` here. You're using forwarding references with your templated && types, which means that they might actually be lvalues which the rest of the program expects to remain valid. `std::move` is basicall a promise that says "The owner is done with this object; feel free to plunder it". Obviously that's dangerous if it's false! `std::forward`, by contrast, will intelligently say whether something is free to plunder, based on whether it was free for plundering when passed as a parameter in the first place.

One other thing that I would suggest might be helpful is adding some sort of error detection. It would take a bit of work, but stuffing `compose` with a few well placed static_assert lines or similar would make a world of difference when trying to get something to build which has a few layers of composition. I'm thinking you could construct something helpful with [is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) although that would require c++17.

Comment: Thank you! I struggled with static asserts a bit, yet succeeded in implementing them after all. Here are the results: https://github.com/nestoroprysk/FunctionComposition/commit/a3221ef53721c161f43072d07d02399903687b2c